# Trace of the product of a Lie algebra and Lie group element

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-decomposition, trace

Take $U \in SU(n)$ and $X \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$. What is known about

\begin{align}
\text{Tr} (UX)
\end{align}

In particular

- Are there any useful identities that apply here?
- When does $\text{Tr} (UX)$ vanish?
- If we can't answer the previous questions, can we bound the expression? But then what is known about $\text{Tr} (X^2)$?

Comment: Why are you interested in ${\rm Tr}(UX)$?

Comment: I have an expression that involves sums and products of traces of $SU(N)$ matrices, which, from numerical evidence, seems to lie in a particular shape in the complex plane. I've found a set of conditions on the matrices that maps out the boundary of this shape and now I'd like to prove that this is indeed the boundary. So I've applied the transformation $U \rightarrow U+i \epsilon U X$ to the expression, evaluated on the conditions on $U$ that map out the boundary, thinking that maybe this will show that an arbitrary neighborhood is impossible or some condition on the modulus of the expression

Comment: Hi, I am also interested in this question, do you solved it now?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make a lot of progress with it. One thing you might want to do is consider the Taylor expansion of $U_1 = exp(iX_1)$ and see if you can make any progress. For example, near the identity $\text{Tr}(U_1 X_2) \approx i \epsilon \text{Tr}(X_1 X_2)$. Maybe you can do something with the commutator, or with considering individual elements for small matrices, or with inequalities involving the trace of the product of two matrices.